# Unclickable links on <li> items in search box

Tags: html

I am trying to make the search results for list items in search bar hyperlinked and clickable. Looking at the coding I can't see why... This is the coding as I have figured out thus far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.filterDiv {
  float: left;
  background-color: #e42625;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 200px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2px;
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the buttons */
.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  background-color: #050505;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.btn.active {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
</style>
<body>

<h2>Ideas for A Fair Deal for Housing</h2>

<div id="myBtnContainer">
  <button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('all')"> Show all</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('A')"> A</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('B')"> B</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('C')"> C</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('E')"> E</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('G')"> G</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('H')"> H</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('L')"> L</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('N')"> N</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('O')"> O</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('P')"> P</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('T')"> T</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('V')"> V</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('W')"> W</button>
  <button <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for organisation.." title="Type in a name">
<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="https://www.housingtoday.co.uk/a-fair-deal-for-housing/ideas-on-how-to-create-a-fair-deal-for-housing/a2-dominion">A2 Dominion</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://google.com">Google</a></li>
  <li><a href="Bing.co.uk">Bing</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
var UL = document.getElementById("myUL");
// hide the list by default
UL.style.display = "none";

var searchBox = document.getElementById("myInput");

// show the list when the input receive focus
searchBox.addEventListener("focus",  function(){
    // UL.style.display = "block";
});

// hide the list when the input receive focus
searchBox.addEventListener("blur", function(){
    UL.style.display = "none";
});


function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    // if the input is empty hide the list
    if(filter.trim().length < 1) {
        ul.style.display = "none";
        return false;
    } else {
        ul.style.display = "block";
    }
    
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        
        // This is when you want to find words that contain the search string
     if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) { 
        li[i].style.display = "";
     } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
    } 
    
    // This is when you want to find words that start the search string
    /*if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().startsWith(filter)) {
        li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
    }*/
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
</button>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <a href="https://www.housingtoday.co.uk/a-fair-deal-for-housing/ideas-on-how-to-create-a-fair-deal-for-housing/a2-dominion"><div class="filterDiv A">A2 Dominion</div></a>
  <div class="filterDiv B">BPHA</div>
  <div class="filterDiv W">WHG</div>
  <div class="filterDiv N">Notting Hill Genesis</div>
  <div class="filterDiv A">Accent</div>
  <div class="filterDiv H">Housing 21</div>
  <div class="filterDiv E">EMH Group</div>
  <div class="filterDiv A">Anchor</div>
  <div class="filterDiv G">Great Places</div>
  <div class="filterDiv P">Paradigm</div>
  <div class="filterDiv B">Bromford</div>
  <div class="filterDiv L">Livewest</div>
  <div class="filterDiv T">Thirteen</div>
  <div class="filterDiv C">Citizen</div>
  <div class="filterDiv H">Hyde</div>
  <div class="filterDiv O">Optivo</div>
  <div class="filterDiv V">Vivid</div>
</div>

<script>
filterSelection("all")
function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("filterDiv");
  if (c == "all") c = "";
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
  }
}

function w3AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {element.className += " " + arr2[i];}
  }
}

function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);     
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}

// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

While trying to resolve this the only searchable terms are A2 Dominion, Google and Bing!

Any guidance would be very helpful. I have also made it so that the list is hidden unless the term is searched for

Thank you in advance!

Comment: because you find the options as soon as blur is called. So when you click the blur is triggered, the options hide, you click nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

epascarello answered this [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73040407/unclickable-links-on-li-items-in-search-box/73042914#comment129002396_73040407):

> because you find the options as soon as blur is called. So when you click the blur is triggered, the options hide, you click nothing.